# xcode c include files

Tags: c, xcode, ide, xcode4

I would like to use XCode 4 as IDE for my C program.

I am using few libraries, which are not installed in system paths. Also, I am using external program for building (waf).

So, basically, I need XCode for everything, except building.

But I can't figure out how to tell XCode where my library include files are for it to be able to autocomplete functions and everything from that libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the build settings for the Target - look for the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` setting.

Have you added the library headers to the project? You can just add them by reference.

Comment: There is only ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS.

Comment: Sorry - I meant look in the Target build settings.

Comment: Same. When creating 'empty' project or 'external build tool' project there is no such setting.

Comment: Yes, I can add them. And autocompletion works after that. But it's very strange problem solve...